# Formatting USB Drive Gives Errors

Tags: boot, 16.04, partitioning, disk, format

I dont know why but this seems to be happening with all of my drives.

I installed Clonezilla on one & after usage tried to format the drive using 'Disk' app in Ubuntu, got errors.

Used another usb for bootable Ubuntu 16.04, after installation, tried to format it using 'Disk' again, got the following error:

> Error deleting partition 
>   Error deleting partition /dev/sdb2:
>   Command-line `parted --script "/dev/sdb""rm2"` exited with non-zero
>   exit status1:Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical lock
>   size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.

How can I format my usbs?

> (udisks-error-quarks, 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mkusb and its wipe menu. See the following links,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[mkusb/wipe](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe)

[image]